# How to make a "If a player steps on X: Z: do this"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a game where if @s steps on X: ? Z:? add to objective "LevelMade"

(Levelmade is an objective where it goes up the more you progress, in this case -- goes up from coords.)

And then, at the end of the game, if the counter is on "1" for example it says:

> It's okay, try harder!

And then if its "2":

> Good Job!
> And so on.

Version 1.19.2

Comment: `execute if block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [execute](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#(if%7Cunless)_entity) command :

```
/execute if entity @p[x=?,y=?,z=?,distance=..0.5] run "your command"
```